# How to blend textures on 2 objects

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am writing a topdown shooter, where the player constantly moves to the right to progress. I cubes (plates) that are used as the floor as the player advances through the game.
Each plate has a different texture - snow, grass, etc - which I choose at random.
The question - how do I blend the textures on one plate with the following plate. I assume I will have to spawn them overlapping, but I don't know what technique to use to gradually transition from one to the other.
I'm not looking for a full written solution, just a nudge in the right direction so I can look up the right terms to start learning how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

**Vertex Colors**: You could color each cube with vertex colors, but that would typically limit you to 3 or 4 different textures to blend between... Also the transition is hard when the cubes are just overlapping. If you have a single object (consisting of connected cubes) you could make use of the blended vertex colors.

[image: blended vertext colors]

The texture blending can be achieved like this:
Vertex Colors blue and black, you can see the blending between the areas (blurry gradient)
[image: Vertex Colors]

If you blend like this:

[image]

You will get this:
[image]

And if you also use a height-map + PBR maps, it can look like this:
[image]

I guess this approach is very limiting to the number of possible blocks.

**Tiles:**

Like in 2D Tile Editors, you need to model/texture different objects to use between your cubes. Example:

Grass Cube - Transition Cube - Sand Cube

And then you need a transition Cube for every possible transition.

The amount of required transitions grows fast when you add base blocks!

[image]

[Tiles Source Kenney.nl](https://www.kenney.nl/assets/rpg-base)

That could be combined with [Wave Function Collapse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_function_collapse) which was used in [TownScaper](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_1fvJ5sHh6A).

Comment: I actually think the 1st approach could work maybe. Let's say I'll select 2 textures assign each to 1 half of the cube, and blend them. How would I go about assigning 2 textures to the material and then blending them?

Comment: I edited my post to show how to actually blend textures using the vertex colors.